# How can I virtualize canvas?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

How can I virtualize canvas? When I add just about 1500 items to canvas, it just freezes for a while and then I get the output on the screen. How can I virtualize it's UI so that Canvas only occupies memory for the elements which are on the screen and Ignores all the rest until they come in the "view"? I want the effect much like VirtualizingStackPanel. VirtualizingStackPanel can handle even 15000 items very nicely.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: why not use a VirtualizingStackPanel then?

Comment: @Xin: Very Smart answer indeed :d. Would I not have used it if it was applicable to my scenario?

Comment: @Xin: Can I manually set the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left of the items that I want to add to the Canvas? Is it possible with VirtualizingStackPanel?

Comment: @Xin: To further clarify it, I am generating a figure where I need to manually set the Top and Left of the element added to Canvas based on some calculation.

Comment: :) hmm... can you use your figure's Margin property instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to derive your own canvas class and override the `LayoutUpdated` event, removing all children that are not in the visible range, or something to that effect.